# Transform XML to another XML using XSL based on some condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML -

```
<root>
 <gereratorList>
    <generator>
        <id>1</id>
        <A>123</A>
    </generator>
    <generator>
        <id>10</id>
        <A>456</A>
    </generator>
    <generator>
        <id>111</id>
        <A>789</A>
    </generator>
</gereratorList>
</root>
```

I want to transform this XML into another XML through XSL. The resulting XML should be something like this -

```
<parent>
    <child>
            <test>456</test>
    <child>
</parent>
```

But I am getting the following XML after transformation -

```
<parent>
    <child>
            <test>123 456 789</test>
    <child>
</parent>
```

My XSL is the following -

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="parent">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="root/generatorList/generator"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/generatorList/generator">
<xsl:element name="child">
     <xsl:if test="/root/generatorList/generator/id='10'">
        <xsl:element name="test">
            <xsl:value-of select="A"/>
        </element>
     </xsl:if>
</element>
</template>
</stylesheet>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xsl is not valid
This one is correct and gives you the result expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="parent">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/gereratorList/generator"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="generator">    
  <xsl:if test="id='10'">
    <xsl:element name="child">
     <xsl:element name="test">
       <xsl:value-of select="A"/>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, there is little differences.

Your mistakes are :

- closing tags are not correct (`</element>` instead of `</xsd:element>`)
- if test is not on the current generator node, but on all nodes

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead:

**Note:** The is spelling difference for `gererator`(in XML) to your XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <parent>
        <child>
            <test>
                <xsl:value-of select="root/gereratorList/generator[id = '10']/A"/>
            </test>
        </child>
    </parent>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gaurav,

Please use below XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"`xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="generator">

<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test = "id = 10">
<parent>
<child>
<test>
<xsl:value-of select ="A"/>
</test>
</child>
</parent>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```